# unity object so fast it goes through solid matter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation

I model a swing that has its own drive. This drive consists of a housing and a weight inside it. The weight is accelerated with an electromagnetic field, so that it hits the wall of the housing at high speed and thus sets the swing in motion.
I am farely new to unity but i thought i did everything correct. At the push of a button the weight was accelerated, hit the housing and the swing startet moving. It worked very well until i started to increase the force which is accelerating the weight (The weight is pretty small, so it needs a lot of speed to move the swing). Now the weight is flying out of the housing. I checked all collision boxes. They are correct and i even made them overlapping to ensure this is not the mistake. I have no idea how to fix this problem and would be grateful for any help.
Here is the code that accelerates the weight, in case you need it:

```
if (rightPressed)
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * forceSlider.value, ForceMode.Impulse);
    rightPressed = false;
}
else if (leftPressed)
{
    leftPressed = false;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * -forceSlider.value, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: Set the rigidbody to be continuous dynamic and mark the house as a static object.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. If you want you can write an answere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fast moving objects make sure to set the [`Rigidbody.collisionDetectionMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html) to [`CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic.html)

Comment: Would marking the house as static also help with this?

Comment: @TEEBQNE not with the accuracy itself but of course it might improve performance .. brings some side-effects though different/baked lightning etc